# Config standard SiteUsers WebPart in SP2010

Tags: web-part, elements-xml, web-part-property

I´ve got a problem with a normal SiteUsers WebPart. Currently I have this code:

```
<WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Group Member</Title>
  <FrameType>TitleBarOnly</FrameType>
  <Description>Use the Site Users Web Part to see a list of the site users and their online status.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>Right</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>6</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>false</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/msmeml.gif</PartImageLarge>
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
  <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.MembersWebPart</TypeName>
  <DisplayType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Members">GroupMembership</DisplayType>
  <MembershipGroupId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Members">26</MembershipGroupId>
  <Toolbar xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Members">false</Toolbar>
</WebPart>
```

Now I need to put a variable GroupID into the MembershipGroupID. I can read out the property via jQuery, thats not the problem but how can I set this GroupID to the SiteUsers WebPart, to display the Users in the group. Can I simply put in a Script into the WerbPart Config? Would be nice, if it would work with JavaScript/jQuery.

The background off all is, that I created own groups, so there is no Members group anymore.

Thanks for all effort.